# How do I indicate a localization project on my resume?

Tags: resume

I'm putting together a new resume, and one of my projects at a previous position involved a localization piece converting our app from English to Chinese (complete with redesign). I was wondering what the best way to indicate this project on a resume? It was my first time as a PM on one of these so I just want to make sure that I get the terminology right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably did two things: Internationalisation and localisation.

Internationalisation is the process of changing an app so that it can be reasonably easy translated into other languages. For example, that involves making buttons not a fixed size, not hard coding string in your app which makes translation impossible, and so on.

Localisation is the process of adding a second, third, fourth language to an app.

Comment: Make sure to mention the "redesign" aspect on a CV.  If you just talk about internationalisation and localisation, people may think you did no more than slap some different text in some fields.

Comment: So we worked with a translator and then I had this huge project of converting our UI for chinese markets, everything from whether or not indicators were present to overall color schemes and brandings, in addition to a few logo and font adjustments. We moved away from fixed size assets at about that time as well. So if that's the case, in bullet points would it be something like "Directed internationalization and localization projects for chinese markets?"

Comment: @dan1111: Someone who thinks internationalisation is slapping some different text in some fields is in for a big surprise when they actually have to do it.

Comment: @TamHartman since it was a huge project, don't trivialize it by condensing it all down to 8 words on a single bullet point.  Maybe keep the single bullet point, but put several sentences there - "worked with a translator", "color schemes and branding", "away from fixed sized assets", "localization", "internationalization", etc.

Comment: +1 for pointing out internationalisation. The OP did not localise it, the translator did. Best to leave that out unless you want to claim translation skills. Internationalisation is a big job but it doesn't require a specialist translating skillset. So something like 'Total redesign of XXX for internationalisation' with areas covered.